# Using the ternary operator to return lowest value from three variables

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I have three variables, all of the integers.

```
indexA
indexB
indexC
```

Now, using the ternary operator, how can I return the lowest value amongst the three?

Comment: Why such a requirement (ternary operator)? Is this homework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following

```
result = indexA < indexB ? Min(indexA, indexC) : Min(indexB, indexC);
```

should do what you want, assuming you can use other operators and methods...

Answer (score 4):

try

```
var lowestVal = (indexA < indexB ? indexA : indexB) < indexC ? (indexA < indexB ? indexA : indexB) : indexC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be the ternary operator? Using `Min<>()` seems simpler.

```
[TestMethod]
public void FindMinimum() {

    int indexA = 6;
    int indexB = 7;
    int indexC = 1;

    Assert.AreEqual(1, new[] { indexA, indexB, indexC }.Min());

}
```

Comment: Well I was thinking in terms of simplicity of the code. But performance is also what I need.

Comment: Is this slower? If slower, is the difference enough to be noticed?

Comment: i have not tested it for speed.

Comment: It's not slower if you compare 3 items, so for sake of simplicity, I would use `IEnumerable.Min()`

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski, your suggestion seems to be even neater. But I have not tested it for speed. But should be reasonably quick enough!

Comment: `.Min()` uses a single pass to iterate all objects in a collection and find the lowest one, which is the fastest way. Like I said, in your specific case, it makes no difference in speed, just that I prefer using `.Min()` for clarity :)
http://pasteit.com/16683